# Is there an SCTP implementation or library that is working on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, sctp

I am working on a python project that lets a client and server communicate and send data but it has to be using SCTP protocol, is there any idea where I can find such thing? I read online that Windows doesn't support SCTP. I don't mind wiriting a python wrapper for a C implementation or any other language. Thanks

edit: I have tried [this](https://github.com/philpraxis/pysctp) but it doesn't support Windows, I am also trying [this](http://www.sctp.de/sctp-download.html) and [this](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp) but so far nothing is working!

Comment: What about https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysctp/0.6 ?

Comment: @Adonis I've already checked it, It doesn't support Windows

Comment: Then could you please include in your question what you have already checked so far?

Comment: @adonis I just did, thanks